# Rebuilding VSCode/WSL2 dev container errors with Too many open files @ rb_sysopen

Tags: vscode-devcontainer

Just trying to get up to speed on dev containers but I've hit a snag already :(

I successfully created a dev container from the typescript-node template. Next I wanted to add mysql so I edited the devcontainer.json and added to the features like this:

```
{
    "name": "Node.js & TypeScript",
    "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/typescript-node:0-18",

    "features": {"ghcr.io/devcontainers-contrib/features/mysql-homebrew:1":{}}
}
```

Then I ran "Dev Containers: Rebuild and reopen in container" which eventually fails

```
[2023-03-15T19:20:13.549Z]  => => # ==> Installing mysql                                                  
 => => # ==> Pouring mysql--8.0.32.x86_64_linux.bottle.tar.gz                  
[2023-03-15T19:20:13.549Z]  => => # Error: Too many open files @ rb_sysopen - /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/mysql/8.0.32/lib/plugin/libtest_sql_stmt.so
```

So I've been trying to increase the max number of open files in WSL with no luck - there are so many "solutions" online but I haven't found anything that actually works.

Help!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm having the same problem...

Comment: No solution yet. I've (theoretically) increased the open files max with no effect on my OS. So, maybe the error is coming from a container? I'm a Docker noob so I don't know for sure and I haven't figured out how to diagnose.